# Parsing csv text to create bootstrap divs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a Bootstrap 3 image gallery with lots of recurring divs that look like this:

```html
<figure class="col-1 picture-item" data-groups='["groupA"]' data-date-created="2018" data-title="imageA">
    <div class="picture-item__inner">
        <div class="aspect aspect--60x60">
          <div class="aspect__inner">
            <img class="myImg" src="imageA.gif" alt="description of image A"/>
      </div>
        </div>
        <div class="picture-item__details">
          <div class="picture-item__tags" style="display: none;">image A keywords</div>
          <p class="picture-item__title">Image A</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</figure>
   
<figure class="col-1 picture-item" data-groups='["groupB"]' data-date-created="2019" data-title="imageB">
    <div class="picture-item__inner">
        <div class="aspect aspect--60x60">
          <div class="aspect__inner">
            <img class="myImg" src="imageB.gif" alt="description of image B"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="picture-item__details">
          <div class="picture-item__tags" style="display: none;">image B keywords</div>
          <p class="picture-item__title">Image B</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</figure>
```

I'm hoping to save myself some time and coding by pulling data from a csv file to create the multiple divs. There are already over a hundred images going into the ever-expanding gallery. The csv data for the above would look like this:

```html
Image A,imageA,groupA,2018,description of image A,image A keywords
Image B,imageB,groupB,2018,description of image B,image B keywords
```

^and so on...

I'm hoping for some help or advice on the best way to achieve a scenario whereby I just need to upload the images with the correct naming convention and update the spreadsheet. I have limited knowledge, but am thinking PHP might be the way to do this?

I hope this question makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working with:

```html
<?php
$fileHandle = fopen("gallery-data.csv", "r");
while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
?>
     <figure class="col-1 picture-item" data-groups='["<?php echo $row[3] ?>", "<?php echo $row[5] ?>"]' data-date-created="<?php echo $row[2] ?>" data-title="<?php echo $row[4] ?>">
      <div class="picture-item__inner">
        <div class="aspect aspect--60x60">
          <div class="aspect__inner">
            <img class="myImg" src="gallery/<?php echo $row[4] . '/' . $row[0] . '.gif" alt="' . $row[6] ?>"/>
      </div>
        </div>
        <div class="picture-item__details">
          <div class="picture-item__tags" style="display: none;"><?php echo $row[7] ?></div>
          <p class="picture-item__title"><?php echo $row[0] ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </figure>
<?php
}

 fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP has two functions for parse csv:

fgetcsv(file,length,separator,enclosure) 
AND
str_getcsv(string,separator,enclosure,escape)

fgetcsv sample:

```
 $file = fopen("contacts.csv","r");

 while(! feof($file))
 {
   print_r(fgetcsv($file));
 }

 fclose($file);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Due to my limited understanding, this only provides a small piece to my puzzle. I successfully apply the code to return the contents of the csv as a series of arrays, but I have no idea how to extract elements of each array into my divs, and in a loop to repeat the divs. Using my original example, the PHP returns the following:

Array ( [0] => Image A [1] => imageA [2] => groupA [3] => 2018 [4] => description of image A [5] => image A keywords) Array ( [0] => Image B [1] => imageB [2] => groupB [3] => 2018 [4] => description of image B [5] => image B keywords) etc etc